# How to check in my plugin whether the user has bought a product in the j2store or not

Tags: joomla-3.x, j2store

I am going to write a plugin for **J2store** to check if the current user has purchased the product successfully or not.
I do not know how to use the **J2store API** to check if the user has purchased the product successfully or not
please guide me...

For example, suppose I have the user ID and the Joomla content ID that was converted to a product by the j2tore. Now how do I check with the J2store API that the user has purchased the product?

Comment: Asking for a professional developer to give you a complete tutorial on how to write a plugin is something that Joomla professionals get paid for.  If you are seeking a coding mentor, JSE is not the right place to advertise.  Please research and attempt to write the plugin; then when are are stuck, ask for help to fix your isolated problem.

Comment: @mickmackusa I know how to write plugins with Joomla, but I have a problem with  j2store api . because the documentation in j2tore is weak for this section.

Comment: Can you please show some/any details in terms of: links to their (bad) documentation, what your current attempt looks like, related content on another platform (Joomla Forum, random forum, user group discussion, dialogue had with their support, etc.). Adding relevant details improves the context of your question and allows researchers and contributors to make progress based on your efforts.  I do truly wish for you to have a good experience here, but I am not personally capable of helping.  Please add relevant details as an [edit].